# Failed to parse the request body: Unhandled error (Failure "Unexpected data (Chain_id)")

Tags: node, api

I am attempting to call run_operation but I am getting the error mentioned in the title. If I remove the chain_id then I get a different error telling me it needs the chain_id.

I am running my own node from the "mainnet" branch. It is a few commits old - from Feb. 11, 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the the chain_id returned from the /chains/main/chain_id looks like this:
""Net...\n"" which the run_operation did not like

Comment: I understand from this self answer that indeed the body of `run_operation` should be `{ "chain_id" : "Net...", ... }` and not `{ "chain_id" : "\"Net...\"\n", ... }` if you end up with that you somehow need to "unquote" what you received from /chains/main/chain_id before feeding run_operation with it :-)